# Creating Constructor in Java - Using "Options" as Parameter

Tags: java, javascript, object, parameters, constructor

I am trying to create an object in Java that takes "options" as a param.

I'm more familiar with javascript - this is how I would write it.

```
function Person(options) {
    for (var prop in options) {
        this[prop] = options[prop];
    }

    var registerUser = function() {
        console.log(options.name);
    }

    registerUser();
}

var chris = new Person({
    name: 'Chris',
    age: '23'
});

var molly = new Person({
    name: 'molly',
    age: '41'
});
```

- Does java support this ?

~~ Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your definition of `options`? Any parameter?

Comment: correct, this[prop] = options[prop] would grab that instance's property and value

Answer (score 0):

No, Java is a bit more verbose with these things - your `Options` class must be predefined, and you need to assign each property one by one. Normally in Java you'd have a Builder. For this particular case it looks quite an overkill, but it lets you have an immutable `Person` that you can configure with the builder.

Another option that is more hacky is to use reflection or `BeanUtils`/ `PropertyUtils` from apache commons-beanutils. So you pass a `Map<String, Object>`, then iterate the map and set each property to the `Person` object.

A builder may look like this:

```
public class PersonBuilder {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public PersonBuilder withName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
   }

   public PersonBuilder withAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
   }

   public Person build() {
       return new Person(this);
   }
}

public class Person {
   private String age;
   private String name;

   public Person(PersonBuilder builder) {
      //assign properties one by one
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for varargs? Something like:

```
public Person(String... args){
   String name = args[0];
   String x = args[1];
}

Person p = new Person("Billy", "testing");
```